# Use two databases to display information

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, arrays, database-design, ssis

I am currently developing a web application with ASP .NET and C# that shows many different startups. The web application uses two different data sources to display the information. Both DBs are local MSSQL databases. 
I've written a small Java program which automatically downloads the data every week from the Crunchbase Database (via API) and puts it in a JSON-file (array). After that the integration service (SSIS) deletes the whole content of my database and fills it with the updated data. 
I use my second local MSSQL database for manual startup entries or to supplement the entry of the CrunchbaseDB with my own information on the website.
The startup web application shows information of both DBs. For example the startup "Kickstarter" has the following information:

- Name (source: CrunchbaseDB (local))
- Location (source: ManualDB)
- Country (source: CrunchbaseDB)
- Description (source: ManualDB)

Both DBs are local MSSQL. How should I handle the cooperation of these two DBs? How should I handle it, when I want to edit/update information from the Crunchbase DB(mssql) although the DB will be deleted every week? Can anybody help me with this complicated approach? Thank you!

Comment: Do these have to be in separate DBs? can you not put them into separate tables that you then JOIN?

Comment: Unless you've missed something from your description, there is no need to have two databases. One would be far better - you'll have all sorts of headaches synchronising and comparing data between two databases. Tables in one database would be far better. You could prefix the table names in the database Man_ and Cru_ so you can logically view it as two databases?

Comment: Yes this would be the better idea. Thank you :) But that is not the main problem. How would you edit/update information in the database that automatically deletes itself every week? The weekly update process is necessary, so the information stays up to date. But my manual entries shouldn't be deleted. Only the information that Crunchbase provides me.

Comment: Do you mean you edit some of the entries, and don't want those overridden by what you download?

Comment: Exactly. Every manual entry i make/update must stay.